# Disable default key binding in evil mode for evil leader

Tags: evil

I'm using evil-leader and bind the leader key to `<SPC>`. Evil-leader config follows after evil-mode in .emacs file.

**Problem**: Sometimes when I hits `<SPC>`, it uses default forward char of evil-mode.

I added this line to unset the key.

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "SPC") nil)
```

It still doesn't help. So I `M-x` + evil-leader-mode every time the problem occur.

My full code is as below:

```
;; evil-mode
(evil-mode t)    

(require 'evil-leader)
(global-evil-leader-mode)
(setq evil-leader/in-all-states 1)
;; unbind evil dafault SPC of forward char
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "SPC") nil)
(evil-leader/set-leader "<SPC>")
(evil-leader/set-key
  "f" 'helm-find-files)
```

Answer (score 2):

[Per documentation on evil-leader Github site](https://github.com/cofi/evil-leader):

> Note: You should enable `global-evil-leader-mode` before you enable
>   `evil-mode`, otherwise `evil-leader` won’t be enabled in initial buffers
>   (`*scratch*`, `*Messages*`, …).

Comment: Please provide a link to the documentation you mention.